# What are the units in Age of Mythology saying?

Tags: terminology, age-of-mythology

What are the units saying in Age of Mythology? For example, when I click on a Hoplite he says "Prostagma". What does that mean?

Is there a resource that has all the unit's quotes for all the races (Greek, Egyptian and Norse) and translated?

Comment: One small caveat: It's still unknown exactly how ancient egyptian is supposed to sound. Even for the language as spoken in the new kingdom we only know with reasonable certainty how non-vowel parts of fragments of the language sound. As there's no agreement, reconstructing the hieroglyphs from the sound of the voices in the game might be a very hard task, as there's so little data to go by.

Answer (score 15):

Someone recently posted one about Norse unit sounds in the Steam Community [here](http://steamcommunity.com/app/266840/discussions/0/412449508294991662/):

> #### All Units
>
> Já (yow) - Yes (both question and affirmative)
>   Ég vil (yer vil) - I will. (I want to)
>   Skipan? (skeepan?) - Orders / commands?
>   Samþykkt (samm-thickt) - Agreed.
>   Tilbúinn! (til-pwin) - Ready!
>
> #### Villagers
>
> Veiðimaður (vey-thee-mathur) - Hunter.
>   Fjósamaður (fyoh-sa-mathur) - Farmer. (literally "Barn man")
>   Timbursveinn (timber-svait-n) - Woodcutter. (literally "timber-lad")
>   Grjótsveinn (groht-svait-n) - Miner. (literally "rock-lad")
>   Satt (saht) - Right. (literally "truly")
>   Hver er þar? (kwer-air-thar) - Who is there?
>
> #### Attacking
>
> Til orrustuslag! (till-orr-ustu-slah) - To battle!
>   Sækið fram! (sigh-keeth-framm) - Advance forward! / Ride forth!
>   Atrás! (art-trouse) - Attack! (I believe it's a combination of two words, literally "at" (fight) + "árás" (battle))

Comment: Damn. Without playing this in years I can recognize most words and 'say' them in my head. Thanks for the nostalgic feeling!

Answer (score 14):

"Prostagma?" means "Orders?" in Greek.

I have found a partial list of translations [here](http://answers.google.com/answers/threadview/id/266125.html). It includes most of the common ones.

Comment: Thanks. Sadly, the list is Greek only. If we had a translator on arqade, i'm sure we would have this finished. +1 for effort.

Comment: Just as a side note: The link provided suggests that the languages are Ancient Egyptian and Ancient Norse. This means there are probably no online dictionaries available for this.

Comment: The Norse speak old Norse which is closest to Icelandic. We only need a rough translation though, so we should be able to find out what they are saying with an icelandic person.

Answer (score 8):

## Ancient Greek (Greeks)

### Expressing Readiness:

> Etimos: Ready (masculine)
>   Etimi: Ready (feminine)
>   Prostagma?: Orders?
>   Lege!: 1. Speak! 2. (Archaic) Collect!

### Agreeing:

> OrthosS: Right.
>   Malista: Very well. / Yes, sir!
>   Ne: Yes
>   kalos: Good, well.
>   Vulome: I want to...

### Job Descriptions:

> metalefs: metal worker (miner)
>   thirefTIS: Hunter
>   vouforgos: I think this means cow herder, which is quite surprising,
>   because the peons say it when they forage.
>   drytomos: oak cutter
>   agrotis: farmer (cf. the word agriculture)

### Battle Commands:

> Pame!: Let’s go!
>   Proseche!: Careful!
>   eis Machin!: To the battle!
>   eisvoli: Invasion!